# IE9 problems with css such gradient background and rounded corners and shadow

Tags: css, gradient, rounded-corners, shadow, internet-explorer-9

I use a gradient background color for selected or hovered menu items it works fine in chrome,FF,opera,ie7,ie8 . but in ie9 the background of the elements appears in the right of the element but text keeps in place this is the first problem.

the second problem i faced is the rounded corner it works fine in chrome, FF, opera but in ie9 the corners are ok but the background of the box was an image but it appears white!!!

the third problem is that of shadow
i apply shadow to the divs containing images it works fine in all browsers but ie9 offset the whole div instead of applying shadow and opacity change on mouse over increased the problem by adding black parts in the side of div that doesn't have shadow???????

when i heard that ie9 supports css3 i knew that this is unbelievable ie will still be my Nightmare!!

I'm afraid of future appearance of the website in ie 9 so i add this
**`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7.5"/>`**

when i used IE=7 or IE=8 the problem still as it is
but know it appears better after adding that line but with no support for rounded corner.

Comment: IE9 is in Beta, things are not guarantee to work at this stage yet, here is a good guide for developers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705

Comment: I've  read this guide but no way

Answer (score 1):

How are you telling IE9 to implement the corners and gradients? Are you using the IE filters (like I assume you're using for 7 and 8)? Or are you actually using CSS3?

If you're using filters, try making IE9 just use CSS3. You can put the filters into their own stylesheet and just use conditional comments to target IE8 and below for them, so IE9 ignores the filters altogether, that way you know they're not interfering.

Comment: i'm using CSS3 for future and -moz- fore Firefox and -webkit- for safari and chrome and the filters also for IE8 and lower I've changed the order by putting CSS3 last to be the dominant but nothing changed and I tried to remove filter and check CSS3 only it gives me th rounded corner but the background becomes white instead of my background image!!!

Comment: Can you update your post to include your code? Perhaps it has to do with a syntax error, or some quirk in your order. Letting some fresh sets of eyes look at it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Sorry i had to finish it at time i replaced the css gradient background with gradient image and i neglected rounded corner in all ie, but i revised it many times and i think there were no errors in html and css. and when i tried to use rounded corners alone with solid  background color it worked and when i tried to use css gradient background without rounded corners it worked !!!! the problem is in their combination .